# Java CompletableFuture - main class not terminated

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I am trying to implment CompletableFuture which invokes a dummy callback method when completed.

However, after adding CompletableFuture.get() method my main class doesn't terminate. 
I tried replacing CompletableFuture.get() with Thread.sleep(5000) but it doesn't seem to be right approach.
Please suggest what is causing CompletableFuture.get() to keep blocking even if the thread is complete.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CallableAsyncWithCallBack {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  CompletableFuture<String> compFuture=new CompletableFuture<String>();
  compFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
   //Compute total
   long count=IntStream.range(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE).count();
  return ""+count;
  }).thenApply(retVal->{ 
   try {
    return new CallBackAsynchClass(retVal).toString();
   } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return "";
  }
  );
 System.out.println("Main Thread 1");
 try {
  compFuture.get();
 } catch (ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 System.out.println("Lock cleared");
 }

}

class CallBackAsynchClass
{
 String returnVal="";
                 public CallBackAsynchClass(String ret) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

                  System.out.println("Callback invoked:"+ret);
                  returnVal=ret;
                 }
                 @Override
                 public String toString() {
                  return "CallBackAsynchClass [returnVal=" + returnVal + "]";
                 }


}
```

I am expecting "Lock cleared" to be outputted but .get() seems to be holding up the lock.

Answer (score 0):

`.thenApply` function returns a new instance of `CompletableFuture`, and it's this instance that you need to use, try using this way instead :

```
public class CallableAsyncWithCallBack {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<String> compFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            //Compute total
            long count = IntStream.range(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE).count();
            return "" + count;
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> future = compFuture.thenApply(retVal -> {
            try {
                return new CallBackAsynchClass(retVal).toString();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ""; });

        System.out.println("Main Thread 1");

        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Lock cleared");
    }

}
```

Hope this helps